# Trying to replace a textarea with better option

Tags: javascript, textarea

Can't seem to figure out the best way to do this.

I am passing through some text to a textarea, but the text is formatted in a mimic of a column format as such:

```
Text          Value    Comments
Text2         Value    Comments
Longtext      Value    Comments
etc...
```

My users take the text from this area and copy/paste it into word. As you can imagine, the attempt at column formatting becomes distorted.

Is there a better way to create this column type of text data set, instead of within a `textarea`?

Comment: `pre` element accepts a tab character (`\t`).

Comment: Will it also line wrap, if the `pre` is located within a fixed width div?

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Sure, I'll test it out and see if there is a difference with the copy/pasting within the text. The line wrap can be adjusted via css as `white-space: pre-wrap;`. Thanks.